# Reduce nested array of objects to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested, reduce

I have an array like

```
Const array=[
{
id:1,
name:"abc",
Address:[
   {
    City: "something",
    Country: "first country"
   },
   {
    City: "other city",
    Country: "country"
    }
  ]
},
{
...........
}
];
```

I have to display this nested array objects as flat key value list. So How to reduce this like below.

```
Reducedarray = [
  { Id: 1, name: "abc" },
  { City: "something", country: "first country"},
  { City: "other city", country: "country"},
  { Id: 2, name: "bbc" },
  { City: "bbcsomething", country: "fbbct country"},
  { City: "other city", country: "country"}
]
```

Using reducearray i will map with object keys and display as key value list in html.

Need to display as flat list using jsx like below

Id: 1
Name: abc
City: first ity
Country: firstcountry
City: second city
Country: second country
Id:2
Name: another name
.....
......
....

Can anyone help me on this plz.. is it possible with reduce only?

Comment: is it mandatory you use reducearray? or anything else is fine?

Comment: Not accepting for loops and nested maps at reviewer end. He mentioned to use reduce for outer array. That is the confusion. Because even after reducing i have to show key value pair with jsx.

Comment: for loops can show key value pair, using for(x in y) loop, x is the key, but I understand you if not accepting nested map, tho i havent tried it, thinking about a way around it, seems sort of inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with reduce:

```js
const data = [{ id: 1, name: "abc", Address: [{ City: "something", Country: "first country" }, { City: "other city", Country: "country" }] }, { id: 2, name: "dfe", Address: [{ City: "something1", Country: "second country" }, { City: "city", Country: "new country" }] }];

const Reducedarray = data.reduce((acc, { Address, ...rest }) => (
  [...acc, rest, ...Address]
), []);

console.log(Reducedarray );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const array= [
{
id:1,
name:"abc",
Address:[
   {
    City: "something",
    Country: "first country"
   },
   {
    City: "other city",
    Country: "country"
    }
  ]
},
];

const array2 = []

for(let el of array) {
  
    if(el.id) array2.push({id: el.id, name: el.name})
    
    if(el.Address) {
        
        for(let element of el.Address) {
          
          array2.push({ city: element.City, country: element.Country})
        }
    }
  
  
}

console.log(array2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a flat map with the destructured rest object and `Address` array.

```js
const
    array = [{ id: 1, name: "abc", Address: [{ City: "something", Country: "first country" }, { City: "other city", Country: "country" }] }],
    result = array.flatMap(({ Address, ...o }) => [o, ...Address]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Yeah but while fetching this array into jsx i need to map with keys right? Is it possible to get only with reduce? Need to display like flat list irrespective of nested array of objects

Comment: do you get the wanted result? why reduce?

Comment: PR ...........?

Comment: Could you please check my jsx result how i need. Sorry i have not applied code tag for that

Comment: I mean code reviewer not accepting all maps and for loops. He mentioned to use reduce

Comment: After this flatmap we have to use object.keys(array) again to render the list. So is there any alternative